# exe icon is not full size (windows 10)

Tags: windows, qt, icons

I want to set an icon for my program (exe file and desktop shortcut). I am using Qt 5.7 on Windows.
I followed the instructions from: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html, that is in the pro file I put "RC_ICONS = logo7.ico".

When I install the program on my computer (Win8), it works well. The desktop shortcut's icon shows my logo perfectly and full size. However, when I install the program on another computer (Win10), the desktop shortcut's icon is not full size. Even if I CTRL-scroll on the desktop to change the icon size, this icon remains the same size.

Here is an example of two desktop icons (one full and the other one that does not scale).
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDE19.png)

Is there something special I should do with my icon (I tried icon sizes of 128x128 to 512x512) so that its full screen ?
Or is it something to do in Qt ?

Thank you so much !

Alex

Comment: Did you put all the standard sizes in the icon file? For me it reads as if you only put one icon size in the file. I normally create 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128, 256x256.

Comment: You need the 256x256 icon in your `logo7.ico` file. You currently have only a 32x32 or 48x48 icon, and it isn't scaling it up because that produces too much ugliness.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information !!
However, I can't seem to be able to change the logo. I replaced the .ico file in my Qt project tree and in the pro file. But it's always the old logo that appears for the .exe.  if I copy paste the .exe, the copied file has the good icon. But if I rename the file to the original .exe, the old logo comes back. If I create a shortcut on the desktop, it has the old logo. I was able to recreate this problem with a bare new project. I have no idea how this can be.....

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a small desktop icon on a W10 Qt app, despite having a 256px icon in the ICO file.  Did you ever find a solution alec?

Answer (score 1):

Most windows 10 .ico icons are multi layer files instead of them being truly scalable. Akin to animated gifs but no animation, just layers. Open a .ico file in Gimp Image editor, you'll see the different sizes in layers. Here is a quick link to the Windows Media center icon hosted on icon archive: http://www.iconarchive.com/show/mega-pack-2-icons-by-ncrow/Windows-Media-Center-icon.html

attached is a screen shot of what I am talking about:

[screen shot of windows media player icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12FVJ.png)

you could use it as a template and replace their pic with yours

Comment: They're not "layered" at all. The ICO format is just a container format that stores multiple bitmaps.

Comment: container, layer, that is just semantics. in gimp they are called layers the also call animated gif frames layers too, but I think its just because its editing what is in the file container

Comment: technically the exe file is supposed to never exist on the desktop. what you have to write an installer (or use one of the several windows installer programs) that will generate the desktop launcher that points to the installation directory that the user installed the whole program (which would include the exe and ico file)  --woops the comment that I respond to was deleted, oh well, I'll leve this comment up just in case its useful for someone..

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, your link was very helpful !! However, I can't seem to be able to change the logo. I replaced the .ico file in my Qt project tree and in the pro file. But it's always the old logo that appears for the .exe. if I copy paste the .exe, the copied file has the good icon. But if I rename the file to the original .exe, the old logo comes back. If I create a shortcut on the desktop, it has the old logo. I was able to recreate this problem with a bare new project. I have no idea how this can be.....

Comment: when you make a shortcut it will use the icon that is inside the exe. when you use a software deployment installer, like install shield or advanced installer, you make it use the ico file when building the desktop icon. Now if you are manually making the shortcut, you have to edit the shortcut and change its icon to the .ico file.